# How do I sort folders by most recently added files in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sorting, files-folders

I use the sort by Date Modified a lot, but this is absolutely useless for folders as it always defaults to when the folder itself was created, not when new files are added to said folder. I need a way to sort all my folders by their most recently added files. Is there a way to do this on windows?

Comment: By search. Search the folders and sort on date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To a limited extent, you can sort on the column *Date last saved*.

[image: Date last saved]

- Right-click on the column header in Explorer.
- Select *More...*
- Scroll down to *Date last saved* and click the check-box to add it.
- Click on that column to sort on it.

Now, if a file is added to a folder, *Date last saved* becomes the date the file was added.

The limitation is that removing the new file does not set the date back -- this column behaves more like *Date last modified* does for files, but for folders, instead.